# displaying index of div using css

Tags: css

I have a bunch of divs like this

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div class="childDiv">some content</div>
    <div class="childDiv">some content</div>
    <div class="childDiv">some content</div>
</div>
```

is there some way using only CSS that I could show the current index to the left of the childDiv elements and it automatically update if I were to shuffle them around using jQuery or would I have to to manipulate the child div using jquery ?

Or 
One of the other ways I was thinking to handle it would be to change them to ol li but then I need them to be zero based and I haven't see any thing in css to do that either

Comment: heh don't know how that happend thanks for the edit @George

Comment: though I'm curious why the down vote

Comment: you have to use js/jquery to edit html to show index value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CSS counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters):

```css
#parentDiv {
  counter-reset: index; /* Create a `index` counter scope */
}
.childDiv:before {
  content: counter(index) ". "; /* Display `index` counter */
  counter-increment: index; /* Add 1 to `index` */
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">
  <div class="childDiv">some content</div>
  <div class="childDiv">some content</div>
  <div class="childDiv">some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: any suggestion on how to make it 0 based index ?

Comment: @mcgrailm Use `counter-reset: index -1` in `#parentDiv` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gyrr36f7/)). Or use `counter-increment: index` in `.childDiv:after` instead of in `.childDiv:before` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gyrr36f7/1/)).